# Assigning multiple conditions to a cell

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a table on Sheet2 of a workbook that tracks incidents. The severity of the incidents are fed from Sheet1 of the same workbook to the D column. The categories are LOW, MED, HIGH and CRITICAL. Each category has a different time range in which it has to be resolved. For example, CRITICAL is 3 days, HIGH is 5 days, MED is 7 days and low is 10. Column E is being fed by column C which has the dates in which we were informed of the incident. Line C has the formula =TODAY()-C1 etc... Is there a way to assign a cell multiple conditions such as "if D3 is CRITICAL, cell E3 will show the number of days it has been pending and if gets past the thresh hold of 3 days, the cell turns red to easily draw attention to overdue items? And if D3 changes category to HIGH, that corresponding range will be applied to E3 and turn red once that item is overdue in relation to the category of D3? I hope I am explaining this right. Thanks in advance!

I have tried conditional formatting and figured out how to assign a color once the amount of days exceed the assigned number. But for example, I cannot figure out how to make the conditions applied to cell E3 be dependent on the category on cell D3

[image]

Comment: That is definitely possible with little effort. However, your verbal description is tedious to follow. Could you insert a screenshot of the desired outcome so that we can clearly see what you are after?

Comment: My apologies for the confusing description. Just added a screenshot. Thank you for looking into.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would *highly* recommend adding a “days overdue” column and then conditional formatting based on that.  Adding more logic to the conditional format function is risky, as circular errors in formatting functions are a common source of sheet corruption.

Your ‘days overdue’ function would be something like `=TODAY()-C2-SWITCH(D2,”Critical”,3,”High”,5,”Medium”,7,”Low”,10)`.  It can be done even easier if you have O365.

Alternatively, you can put a similar formula as the one shown, into your conditional formatting rules, I am just hesitant to recommend that.